# Text Overflow Hidden Breaks Float

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

I need my text to wrap my image which works fine until I set the text overflow the hidden. The reason I need to set it to hidden is because it's going to be half hidden at first. I tried switching back and forth between `visible` and `hidden` but it causes nasty visuals.

What can I do to use `overflow:hidden` an keep the integrity of the `float`?

[A fiddle example of the overflow "bug"](http://jsfiddle.net/zBRJ9/)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set the `overflow: hidden` to the parent container and then toggle that property to expose more text.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/D8QUg/

However, you need to size the `div` carefully so that the  lines don't get cut off in the middle of the character height.